# How do you add a project to svn in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I managed to download the svn plugin for eclipse helios. I then managed to add a new repository to the drive of my choice. However i cannot see how i know add projects i have already created? Can someone tell me how i go about doing this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Something like:

- Right-click on your project.
- Select Team -> Share Project.
- The Wizard will guide you through to make an Initial Import.
- The Initial Import wont actually put any code into the repository, just the project details. So you then need to do:
- Right-Click Team -> Commit, and the same for all future commits.

Comment: ok thanks, i managed to do this just after i posted. However when i go to click in the final stage commit there are not any values in the resources?

Comment: @ricki - the Initial Import will not commit anything. See my last 2 instructions.

Comment: i did understand you, its just when i go to do the final stage it wont let me commit because there are no resources apparently to commit :/

Comment: @ricki: hmmm. that suggests you didn't complete the initial import correctly I think

Comment: Make sure you use "Add to svn:ignore" at this point. Use this for all folders which should not use version control (ie.folders which might have autogenerated content)

Comment: Is it possible to add folders in the projects rather than the entire project in svn repository?

Comment: Unless I am missing something this won't create the usual structure with `trunk`, `branches` and `tags`.  Everything will end up in the project root folder.

Comment: @ForguesR:The location where to add the project into svn (ex http://my.svn.server/svn/FOA/trunk/integration) has to be passed to Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do File -> Import -> SVN -> Checkout projects from SVN...

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project root, and choose `Team | Share project...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Install Tortoise svn, right click on the folder that you want to commit, select svn commit, add the files that you want to commit.

P.S. Before committing just check using repo browser if you are committing to right svn location.