# How to check in new project to SVN for first time using Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project that I checked out from a file location, not from SVN. I have made some changes in the code. Now I need to commit this new code to SVN. But I don't know how to do it. I searced in google and I found this question "[How do you add a project to svn in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716042/how-do-you-add-a-project-to-svn-in-eclipse)". In which its mention like Right Click then "Team -> Share Project" .But in my eclipse I am not getting "share project" option. Please help me.I am using Eclipse Indigo and TortoiseSVN.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mario Cervera for suggestion.

Comment: It sounds like you have not installed SVN in Eclipse.

Comment: no..svn is installed...

Answer (score 0):

```
 In this case you have installed Tortoise SVN on client site then go to workspace where project are existing.

Right Click on this project and add the project whoes commit on svn.
after that ok button click.
The project files have been selected to be added to the repository, 
but the change has not yet been committed.  If you add new fileslater,   
you can use this same method to add them to the existing repository

Committing Changes to the Repository:
A commit will enter your changes into the repository.  Changes will only be entered into the repository when you commit, this includes adding and deleting files.
Right click within the folder and select SVN Commit...
Enter notes in the Message section to describe the changes that are being checked in.  You can also select which modified files should be committed.
Click OK when ready. 


Right-click on your project.
Select Team -> Share Project.
The Initial Import wont actually put any code into the repository, just the project details. So you then need to do:
Right-Click Team -> Commit, and the same for all code commits.
```